# Cache invalidation using Webpack

Tags: google-chrome, caching, nginx, webpack, cache-invalidation

I am appending `hash` ids to bundles generated by `webpack`. Whenever I get a new build I see that filenames are changed with new hash and `index.html` file is referencing these files. But after deploying my app, some users using Chrome don't see the new files until they logout from the app. Does anyone encounter this before, know any solution to fix it?